# Angular 2 ngSubmit.emit() doesn't change the <myform>.form.submitted property

Tags: angular

My following code triggers the `addResult()` method property, but the property submitted is always empty. Any guesses?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="addResult()" #resultForm="ngForm">
    <p>is form submitted? {{resultForm.form.submitted}}</p>
    ...
    <button type="submit" (click)="resultForm.ngSubmit.emit()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="saveDialog">Sauvegarder</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this

1. pass something to the function.
2. remove resultForm.ngSubmit.emit() its unnecessary there.
3. Its just resultForm.submitted
4. created [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E4Npd8Rt2FJNkSCbpFAn?p=preview)

   ```
    <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="addResult(resultForm)" #resultForm="ngForm">
    <p>is form submitted? {{resultForm.submitted}}</p>

   ...
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="saveDialog">Sauvegarder</button>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to say that the submit is in a modal dialog, so, i don't know why, the button doesn't submit the form, and I tried to put the dialog definition inside the <form>. The only way I found to get the addResult called is the .emit(). But not sure its the right thing to do.

Comment: You should put button inside the form for submit to work. another case.just use <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addResult(resultForm)" data-dismiss="modal" id="saveDialog">Sauvegarder</button> and work with form in function